# python equivalent to perl's @{$obj->method($args)} or %{$obj->method($args)}

Tags: python, perl, idioms

Title demonstrates the perl idiom I wish to convey in my python script.  I realize this could be construed as bad practice, potentially due to (lack of) exception handling.  Though nonetheless I find value in performing such operations in (disposable/personal) utilities.

Comment: Python is strictly typed. If `obj.method(args)` returns a sequence(-like) value, just use it as a sequence. If it returns a mapping(-like) value, just use it as a mapping.

Comment: For the Pythonistas unfamiliar with idiomatic Perl hoping to answer, could you actually describe what the idiom is supposed to accomplish and provide examples? As it stands the question itself doesn't actually have content.

Comment: -1: This question alienates many potential future readers and pythonistas by not explaining what this idiom does.

Comment: @array = $obj->method($args) and @{$obj->method($args)} are equivalent in nature.  I'm simply trying to use the returned value without having to assign a variable.

Comment: I don't know Perl, so I can't answer the question. You should really explain what it does

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have the notion of different kinds of variables like Perl has. Scalars, lists and dicts are all stored in the same kind of variable. So this "idiom" is not applicable. Just use the returned value directly.

Some example Perl code:

```
sub foo {
    return [ qw(a b c) ];
}

@list = @{foo()};
say $list[0];
say $list[1];
say $list[2];
```

The equivalent Python code:

```
def foo():
        return ("a", "b", "c")

list = foo()
print list[0]
print list[1]
print list[2]
```

I have no idea what you could mean when you refer to a lack of exception handling.

Comment: My question may have been phrased poorly, quite simply, is there a way to achieve this?  obj.method()['key'] != 0

Comment: @user2390378 Of course. Following my example code, `print foo()[0]` prints `a`.

Comment: sorry it took a while to sink in, must have been that midnight showing of star trek last night :)

Answer (score 0):

The three-letter answer to this question is: huh?

The longer answer: Python doesn't have have references.  There are no tuplerefs, or dictrefs, and there are no functions that ever return them, and there is no means by which a caller can turn the tuplerefs or dictrefs into tuples or dictionaries.  There's no equivalence.

This Perl:

```
sub foo {
  qw/a b c/
}
my @array = foo;
print $array[0];
print $array[1];
print $array[2];
```

Is not 'less equivalent' than the Perl in the other answer to the other answer's Python.

It's different from the other bit of Perl though.  It's particulary different when you look at invocations like:

```
my @array = (this_foo(), this_foo(), this_foo());
# @array is now: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), and one-dimensional.

my @array = (that_foo(), that_foo(), that_foo());
# @array is now: (['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']), and two-dimensional.
```

But it's a difference that's just meangless to Python.